# JSON.stringify returns &quot; instead of ""

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

I'm looking to turn text like this into JSON:

```
Company     Team
Facebook    Marketing
Google      Engineering
Microsoft   Product
```

When I log the JSON.stringify returns `&quot;` instead of `"`. Why does that happen? What can I change to prevent this?

```
let pre = document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML;

var cells = pre.split('\n').map(function (el) { return el.split(/\s+/); });

var headings = cells.shift();

var obj = cells.map(function (el) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = el.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[headings[i]] = isNaN(Number(el[i])) ? el[i] : +el[i];
  }
  return obj;
});


var json = JSON.stringify(obj,null,5);
console.log(json)
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzh7jndt/1/)

Comment: That's just jsfiddle's console that's "buggy" when logging this character in a string: https://jsfiddle.net/qyoLf63j/ If you look at your browser's console you can see it's correctly logged.

Comment: Instead of JS Fiddle you can put your code in SO Code Snippet

Comment: @EzioMercer in this case they can't because the issue is actually caused by jsfiddle. A live stacksnippet wouldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry, he didn't say that this error only in jsfiddle so I decided to add his code to code snippet

Comment: @EzioMercer Yes, I don't think they knew that it was caused by jsfiddle, but as an editor you ought to verify that the snippet you make does reproduce the problem as explained by the asker. If it doesn't, tell them in a comment that you weren't able to reproduce in a snippet and ask them to produce this live example. Anyway, thanks for trying to make the site better and keep up on that.